# What does title mean as in "mobile titles"?

Tags: word-meaning

[image]

I think it isn't the title of a book that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually "Mobile titles" refers to applications,games,etc. created for mobile devices such as Android and IOS(better known as "Smartphones")